# Difference entre « c'était d'hier » et « c'était hier »

Tags: grammaire, de

En lisant un roman, j'ai regardé une phrase

« Comme si c'était d'hier, ... »

Je sais le sens de « c'était hier » mais à quoi sert ici « d'» ?

Edit: 1

Le paragraphe entier,

« Comme si c'était d'hier, je me rappelle le soir où marchant déjà depuis quelque temps, je découvris tout à coup la vraie manière de sauter et de courir, et me grisai jusqu'à tomber de cette chose délicieusement nouvelle. »

C'est un extrait du roman « Le Roman d'un enfant de Pierre Loti »

Comment: Un peu de contexte STP ?

Comment: @livresque Désolé, j'ai ajouté le paragraphe entier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Les deux se disent mais *d'hier*, ça frappe un peu. J'entends beaucoup plus souvent *hier* tout simplement.  Le verbe *s'en souvenir* conviendrait plus avec *d'hier* (se souvenir **de** quelque chose).

*Comme si c'était **d'hier*** évoque *le jour avant* plutôt que *si clair.*

Le [dictionnaire](http://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9H0670) des ordonnances de l'Académie donne ces exemples :

> ▪ Expr. Je m’en souviens comme si cela datait d’hier ou, fam., comme si c’était hier, de manière très précise. Cela ne date pas d’hier, est très ancien.

Il n'y a pas de résultats [NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Si%20c%27%C3%A9tait%20hier%2Csi%20c%27%C3%A9tait%20d%27hier&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3) pour *si c'était d'hier.*

(Il est facile de confondre l'emploi des deux verbes selon l'[A](https://www.academie-francaise.fr/se-rappeler-quelque-chose-se-souvenir-de-quelque-chose)cadémie Française (L'ordonnance Dire, ne pas dire) et il faut utiser le COD avec le verbe *se rappeler* mais c'est une autre boule de gamme.)

Comment: Google NGrams n'analyse pas correctement l'expression, peut être à cause des apostrophes. On en trouve des occurrences par centaines dans la littérature.

Comment: @jlliagre Et moi qui me demandais pourquoi pas !  Merci d'avoir donné de si bons exemples que j'ai manqués.  Je suis d'accord quant aux enjeux descriptifs.

Answer (score 3):

C'est une variante rare, parfois même considérée comme erronée<sup>1</sup>, mais qu'on peut rencontrer chez les meilleurs auteurs.

1. **Comme si c'était hier** : *comme si ça s'était passé hier, comme si on était hier.*
2. **Comme si c'était d'hier** : *comme si c'était d'hier dont je me souvenais/rappelais, comme si ça datait d'hier*.

Exemples :

> *Ainsi je me rappelle, **comme si c'était d'hier**, ma sortie de la maison, vers onze heures du matin, pour aller faire cette visite d adieu.*
> Pierre Loti, *Prime jeunesse*, 1919.

> *Et je me rappelle, **comme si c'était d'hier**, la mélancolie profonde et désolée de ce jour d'octobre qui fut, cette année-là, le dernier des vacances et la veille de la cruelle « rentrée des classes ».*
> Julien Viaud, *Figures et choses qui passaient*, 1898.

> *Voilà la première confession que je fais depuis celle que vous avez reçue un soir, et que vous avez si miséricordieusement en- tendue. Je m'en souviens **comme si c'était d'hier**. Vous m'avez embrassée, vous m'avez juré d'être ma sœur.*
> Louis Ulbach, *Pauline Foucault*, 1859.

> *On partit enfin. Je vois cela **comme si c’était d’hier** : le vapeur chauffant contre le quai de Granville ; mon père, effaré, surveillant l’embarquement de nos trois colis ; ma mère inquiète ayant pris le bras de ma sœur non mariée, qui semblait perdue depuis le départ de l’autre, comme un poulet resté seul de sa couvée ; et, derrière nous, les nouveaux époux qui restaient toujours en arrière, ce qui me faisait souvent tourner la tête.*
> Guy de Maupassant, *Mon oncle Jules, et autres nouvelles*, 1883.

> *Je me rappelle toujours, **comme si c'était d'hier**, d'une des plus belles heures de la traversée ; aucune ne fut plus ineffable. Je m'étais étendu sur le pont ; Manon avait posé son front sur ma poitrine. La nuit était douce et illuminée...*
> Edmond Pilon, *Suite au récit du chevalier des Grieux, La Nouvelle Revue française*, 1909.

> *Eh bien, écoutez, monsieur l'abbé, il y a vingt-six ans que nous sommes ensemble ; oui, vingt-six ans au 15 juin prochain ; eh bien, monsieur l'abbé, foi d'homme d'honneur, nous nous séparerons **comme si c'était d'hier**, et nous finirons le peu de jours qui nous restent à vivre, elle de son côté, moi du mien.*
> Alexandre Dumas, *Catherine Blum*, 1854.

> *Tous les détails de cette enivrante soirée sont dans ma mémoire **comme si c'était d'hier**, et cependant depuis il s'est écoulé bien des jours de découragement et de malheur.*
> Victor Hugo, Lettre à la fiancée, 1822.

> *Dans l’année 1917, il est question de la mort d’Octave Mirbeau. J’ai écrit, absolument de mémoire, un long supplément à ce passage de sa mort, sur son mariage, ses amours, ses changements d’opinion, sa collaboration au journal Le Journal, ma visite et déjeuner chez lui à Triel avec George Besson, tout cela **comme si c’était d’hier**.*
> Paul Léautaud, *Journal littéraire*, 1956.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>L’élève applique la plupart des règles de l’orthographe lexicale et grammaticale
et les erreurs, s’il y en a, ne nuisent ni à la qualité ni à la clarté de la communication
(ex. : « **comme si c’était d’hier** » au lieu de « **comme si c’était hier** » et « L’avantage est que
je peux » au lieu de « L’avantage est que je puisse »). [Alberta Education](https://www.alberta.ca/assets/documents/edc-fr30-1-exemples-de-production-ecrit-2016.pdf)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

It means "it was from yesterday" "it was of yesterday" versus "it was yesterday"